# Check if nullable string property contains anther string with indexOf or includes gives expression expected error

Tags: javascript, typescript, string

I want to assign a value to a const conditionally and need to check if one nullable string property in my object contains another one. Based on this i will assign it the value of functionA or functionB. I have tried to use both 'indexOf' and 'includes' but typescript gives 'Object is possibly undefined' or 'expression expected'. If you hav an idea on how to write this in a way which checks the nullable object and property and evaluate this please let me know, your help is appreciated!

using indexOf gives an error in Typescript Object is possibly 'undefined'

```
const value = (req.object?.propertyA?.indexOf(req.object?.propertyB?) >= 0) ? 
    functionA(req.object?.propertyA?) :
    functionB(req.object?.propertyB?)
```

Using includes to check for the substring shows an error in Typescript with expression expected

```
const value = req.object?.propertyA?.includes(req.object?.propertyB?)  ? 
   functionA(req.object?.propertyA?) :
   functionB(req.object?.propertyB?)
```

Comment: What's with those `?` suffixes? That's not valid Typescript

Comment: What do you want to happen if propertyA or propertyB (or some part of their object) is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from `req.object?.propertyB`.

Both `String.prototype.indexOf()` and `String.prototype.includes()` expect a `string` parameter but your expression can potentially return `undefined`.

The `?` suffix also doesn't make sense.

I would alter your expression to be clearer and check for `propertyB` first...

```ts
const value =
  req.object?.propertyB && req.object?.propertyA?.includes(req.object.propertyB)
    ? functionA(req.object?.propertyA)
    : functionB(req.object?.propertyB);
```

Comment: ahh thank you! ok to add the check earlier since both indexOf and includes expect a string, that works i think...also to your earlier question about the ? suffix it is because of string properties in the model are nullable. If i just try to use req.object without the ? it throws an error 'Object is possibly undefined' which is true with the ? check it is treated as optional

Comment: I'm talking about the suffix, aka last character you added to each property. Good - `req.object?.propertyB` / Bad - `req.object?.propertyB?`

Comment: i see, i think you are correct the last ? on the property is not needed i guess, so if the req.object?propertyA is null or undefined in this case, would the 'includes' throw an error? since it cant do the 'includes' on an undefined or null string? just trying to understand what this would do in the that case

Comment: You seem to be missing what I'm saying. You literally have `indexOf(req.object?.propertyB?)`, `functionA(req.object?.propertyA?)` and `functionB(req.object?.propertyB?)`. Those trailing `?` on each expression are invalid syntax and are the cause of any _"expression expected"_ errors. Note that they are not present in my answer

Comment: @Shokwave `foo.bar?` makes parser think you have an incomplete ternary like `foo.bar ? 1 : 2`. This is what "expression expected means"